# Filtrar datos en un jtable para obtener datos de la bd mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jframe

mi consulta es la siguiente. tengo un
select a varias tablas con left join, el resultado que requiero obtener es que cuando consulto por periodo(año y mes) y grupo (grupo1 grupo2, etc) en mi lista de asistencias, por ejemplo si en enero registre asistencias para el grupo 1 me retorne los valores registrados,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
la idea es que cuando consulto las asistencias para el grupo2 me retorne los campos con nombres de trabajador, grupos y básico para poder registrar la asistencia para el grupo2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cual es tu problema?

Comment: una vez filtrado por periodo(año y mes) y grupo, me retorne valores de las asistencias si es que ya esta registrados me retorne una lista con datos completos.
pero si no tiene registro de asistencias me devuelva los campos los datos: N°  | Trabajador  | grupo  | básico y los campos de la derecha vacíos para registrar

Comment: y que mensaje de error te da ese problema?

Comment: a la hora hacer el filtro para el grupo dos no me retorna los datos

Comment: puedes poner tus imagenes como codigo? porque tal como esta es dificil que alguien lo haga compilar ya que no es un [mcve]